# Why has comma been used to separate two independent clauses?

Tags: punctuation

Why has comma been used to separate two independent clauses?

> 1. The overwhelming power that the Unlawful Activities (Prevention) Act
>    gives to the state, [comma]the sheer impunity with which government
>    can treat this group of accused, the Kafkaesque role of the judiciary
>    in denying bail and making procedural safeguards ineffective, and the
>    deafening political silence on their detention, all warrant deeper
>    reflection.
> 2. And Teltumbde was insightful in thinking that once you had been
>    labelled Left in India,[comma] it was easy to secure a diminution in
>    your legal and cultural standing.
> 3. Putin declares this to be a victory of sorts for him,[comma] he avoids
>    the cost of occupying Ukraine, but does enough to control it, and in
>    his own way, humiliates NATO.

[Sentence 1 and 2](https://indianexpress.com/article/opinion/columns/varavara-rao-covid-19-anand-teltumbde-uapa-act-bhima-koregaon-6511031)

[Sentence 3](https://indianexpress.com/article/opinion/columns/world-must-do-more-to-put-pressure-on-russia-7791262)

Comment: In **1** they are dependent (subordinate) clauses. If we simplify it it says, "_The power, the impunity, the role and the silence all warrant reflection_". **warrant** is the main verb. In **2** - "_Teltumbde **was** insightful_ (in thinking this facilitated this)". **3** seems to me to need a colon rather than the first comma and I would say, "Ukraine, while doing enough to control it, and - in his own way - humiliates NATO."

Answer (score 1):

1. 

> [The overwhelming power that the Unlawful Activities (Prevention) Act gives to the state], [the sheer impunity with which government can treat this group of accused], [the Kafkaesque role of the judiciary in denying bail and making procedural safeguards ineffective], and [the deafening political silence on their detention], all warrant deeper reflection.

Example1 is one independent clause consisting of four noun phases, as bracketed, in a series.  The commas separate the noun phrases, and this use is fine.

2.

> Teltumbde was insightful in thinking that [once you had been labelled Left in India, it was easy to secure a diminution in your legal and cultural standing].

In the original text, there is no *And* starting this clause.

In example 2, the bracketed part consists of a dependent clause and an independent clause.  The use of the comma is fine.

In example 3, the comma after *him* is incorrect as the statement before that is an independent clause.  A full stop or a semicolon would be fine.

This example also has another punctuation error.  The third comma should be placed, instead, after *and* so that the last two commas form a bracketing comma pair.

My suggestion is as shown below:

3.

> Putin declares this to be a victory of sorts for him.  He avoids the cost of occupying Ukraine, but does enough to control it and, in his own way, humiliates NATO.

Answer (score 0):

I have taken the liberty of promoting OLD BRIXTONIAN'S comment to its deserving status as an answer:

In 1 they are dependent (subordinate) clauses. If we simplify it, it says, "The power, the impunity, the role and the silence all warrant reflection". warrant is the main verb.

In 2 - "Teltumbde was insightful (in thinking this facilitated this)".

3 seems to me to need a colon rather than the first comma and I would say, "Ukraine, while doing enough to control it, and - in his own way - humiliates NATO." –
Old Brixtonian
2 hours ago